# What is it about some (or all) of the properties of Hilbert Spaces that makes them so useful/necessary for modeling so many different systems?

Tags: hilbert-space, mathematics, models

To be a Hilbert Space, your space $(V,+,\cdot)$ needs to:

**Be a Vector Space:**

$ \forall u,v,w\in V $ and $a,b\in\mathbb{F}$

1) Associativity of addition -- $u+(v+w)=(u+v)+w$

2) Commutativity of addition --- $u+v=v+w$

3) Identity Element of Addition -- $\exists 0\in V:\forall v\in V, v+0=0$

4) Inverse Element of Addition -- $\forall v\in V \exists -v\in V: v+(-v)=0$

5) Associativity with scalar multiplication -- $a(bv)=(ab)v$

6) Identity Element of Scalar Multiplication -- $1v=v$ for $1\in F$

7) Distributivity of scalar multiplication w.r.t vector addition -- $a(u+v)=au+av$

8) Distributivity of scalar multiplication w.r.t scalar addition -- $(a+b)v=av+bv$

**Have an Inner Product**

$\exists \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V \times V \to \mathbb{F}$ with the properties:

1) Conjugate Symmetry -- $\langle v,w\rangle = \overline{\langle w, v \rangle}$

2) Linearity in the First Argument: $ \langle au, v\rangle=a\langle u,v\rangle$ and $\langle u+v, w\rangle = \langle u,w \rangle + \langle v, w \rangle$

3) Positive Definiteness -- $\langle v, v \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle v,v\rangle = 0 \iff v=0$

**Be Complete**

If a series of vectors converges absolutely, i.e.:

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ||v_n||<\infty$

Then the series converges in the space V.

---

We can used spaces like this to model a vast array of physical systems. Sturm-Liousville Theory and Fourier Analysis rely on the properties of Hilbert Spaces of functions with an inner product defined using integration. These systems solve problems ranging from Classical to Statistical to Quantum Mechanics.

Now, by no means would I expect anyone to list why **all** of these properties are important, but what is it about some of the particular properties of Hilbert Spaces that makes them so useful?

For instance, why is Conjugate Symmetry of the inner product of two elements of the space necessary for describing so many systems? Or Linearity in the First Argument? For that matter, why should all Cauchy sequences of elements be required to converge in the space?

What is it about a complete, (usually) complex inner-product space that makes it so useful in so many ways?

---

P.S. (but not all that important): What exactly is meant when it says that a Hilbert Space generalizes the notion of Euclidean Space?

Comment: You last part: Hilbert space expands calculus and vector algebra into any number of dimension, ( even, or especially perhaps, infinite dimensions) based orginally on the simplest, most straightforward  2 dimensional Euclidean space ideas and axioms. Personally, I think this is more a mathSE type question, as you cover a lot of ground, all based on math concepts. Best of luck with the question anyway.

Comment: The Hilbert space is simply the infinite dimensional harmonic oscillator. Why is it so useful? For the same reason that the harmonic oscillator is useful: it can be calculated with relatively little effort.

Comment: We all agree that Hilbert Spaces as useful and easy to compute with, but my question is more about the specific properties of Hilbert Spaces (like conjugate symmetry with respect to the inner product, or completeness) that make them so useful, and specifically why those properties are useful in modeling so many different systems. What is it about the particular set of properties that Hilbert Spaces have that make them such natural mathematical spaces in which to model

Comment: Why does nature make a lot of harmonic oscillators? It doesn't. We are the ones who are fitting them to everything and anything that we see and we hope that they will work well enough to be useful (whenever they are not, the pain to calculate things goes up a hundred fold). I am getting the feeling that your model of what physics is is not a very precise rendition of what physics actually is.

Comment: Is it misguided to wonder about mathematical connections/similarities between models in various areas of physics? It seems to me somewhat remarkable that Hilbert Spaces are so useful as an underlying framework on which to model such varied phenomena as they do. What I wonder about, and what I hoped this question would explore, is why these *particular* qualifications for a particular type of vector space make it so powerful. Maybe my question is gibberish. Maybe someone knows what I'm getting at.

Comment: I feel you can ask the same question about perturbation theory, Fourier transforms and Taylor expansions, (and conformal transformations using complex numbers). We take the math we have and adapt it. If we  really live in  a mathematical based reality, then it makes sense to me.

Comment: I'm sure you could as the same about many mathematical frameworks - Diff. Geometry for GR, group structures for particle physics. We use whichever structure fits the task. Often many simultaneously. I'm starting to wonder though if my question was rather badly put. It seems to have hit a nerve in some way. I was really just curious about why properties like an inner product on elements of your space with properties like conjugate symmetry would have such a wide array of applications across so many different phenomena they help to model.